# Imagebutton renders incorrectly with doubly-nested layout_weights

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Using these images:

[image] **(333x300)**
[image] **(1680x1050)**

and this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">    

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/apple" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/apple" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">   

        <ImageButton
            style="@style/OtherButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/orange" />

        <ImageButton
            style="@style/OtherButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/orange" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

gives this result:

[image]

With only singly-nested layouts, the apple and orange buttons are the same size.  After messing around with Eclipse, I've noticed the buttons tend to be taller when their images are larger, but the relative proportions don't seem to follow a particular pattern.

**Why do the buttons have different heights?  Is there an alternative method I can use that will scale with screen resolution and density?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make below change.

In your main parent Layout make  layout_height to `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work by changing this and deleting duplicate layout_width/height attributes from my button's style definition.